# How do I add content to the last element in the loop in Wordpress portfolio template

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

In a single-portfolio template, file I have video and text area content. I have custom content and social share icons below video content. Currently, if I have more than 1 video area, the content displays below each video area (because of loop, IMO). I would like have the content display only below the last video area. How can I do this?
My code:

```
elseif( get_row_layout() == 'video' ): 
?>
    <div class="media-embedded mb-40 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <?php 
            if ( inez_get_sub_field('video_link') ) {
                inez_the_sub_field('video_link'); 
            }
        ?>
    </div> <!-- end col-sm-8 -->                                    
    <div class="row mb-40 text-monospace text-dark"> //// my custom content+social share 
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
            <?php the_content();  ?>
        </div> <!-- end col-sm-8 -->
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="mb-20">
                <?php get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'share' ); ?>  
            </div>
            <?php if ( inez_get_field('link') ) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(inez_get_field('link')); ?>" target="_blank" class="link-border"><?php esc_html_e('Visit Site', 'inez'); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end row -->
```

Comment: We need to see how the loop is being constructed. Can you put the code for the entire file into Pastebin so I can review it?

Comment: @Fencer04 my code is here http://pastebin.com/AF30CRK9. My content is 'Flexible Content - Video' for this template. Thanks

Comment: I added some code and made a new Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Ua8cuPEk 

You can search for the initials JSH and you will see the places I added it. I couldn't test it but it should get you started. I'm going to put an answer explaining what I did. It is the correct way to do it but the code could change depending on the surrounding code. If have you specific issues with the code I wrote let me know and I'll help you through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize a variable above the loop that will be used to count the posts, you need to add 1 to this variable each time through the loop and you need to check to see if this variable equals the total post count for the loop where you want to change the loops action. The code below is an example:

```
<?php
    //Set post_count variable - JSH
    $post_count = 0;

    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();  ?>

    //Check to see if this is the last post
    <?php if( $post_count == $wp_query->found_posts ) {
        //This is the last post
    } else {
        //This is not the last post, continue normally
    }?>   

<?php endwhile; endif;?>
```